# How to remove id="node-[nid]" with Display Suite?

Tags: theming, nodes, hooks, display-suite

How I can remove the node id when I override a node layout with Display Suite?

In some (old) how-to I noticed that the id node is not present when a node layout is overridden with DS.

i.e.: from this

```
<div id="node-1" class="ds-1col node node-page clearfix clearfix view-mode-full content clearfix" typeof="foaf:Document" about="/node/1">
```

to this

```
<div class="ds-1col node node-page clearfix clearfix view-mode-full content clearfix" typeof="foaf:Document" about="/node/1">
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the Drupal version and which theme you are using? I noticed that there are 3 `clearfix` in class. It is weird to me.

Comment: Probably by creating a DS custom template

Comment: @JimmyKo : is a my custom theme based on basic theme "Tao". For the 3 clearfix I've solved, it was a my mistake.

Comment: @NoSssweat : the issue is present also without a DS custom template

Comment: It seems like you would have to hack DS, an alternative would be to remove it using jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code is quoted from [template.php](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/tao/tree/template.php?h=7.x-3.x) of [Tao](https://www.drupal.org/project/tao).

```php
/**
 * Implementation of preprocess_node().
 */
function tao_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $vars['hook'] = 'node';

  $vars['classes_array'][] = 'clearfix';

  $vars['attributes_array']['id'] = "node-{$vars['node']->nid}";

  ...
```

The ID is added by this line.

`$vars['attributes_array']['id'] = "node-{$vars['node']->nid}";`

You can override it by implementing the same hook function in **template.php** of your custom child theme.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_node().
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  unset($vars['attributes_array']['id']);
}
```

Comment: Is this assuming he only has 1 `div id` on the node?

Comment: According to the [node.tpl.php](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/tao/tree/templates/node.tpl.php?h=7.x-3.x), I think yes...